# Copy data to excel sheet using SSIS

Tags: ssis

[image][image]

I'm trying to generate excel dynamically using SSIS. I have created an Excel task and mentioned the connection manager as an Excel and created a table for my required columns.

Then, I want to populate the values from the database so I created one DB connection.

But when I'm trying to execute the package it is showing Sheet Name already exists.

Comment: Can you provide more details? are you trying to insert values into a pre-made excel file, or are you trying to create a file from scratch every time?

Comment: Not pre made. In sql task I mentioned create table for excel with excelpath property